# PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, conda

**conda update conda** >> successful

**conda update anaconda** >> gives me error saying package is not installed in prefix.

I have single installation of Python distribution on my system. How do I solve this issue?

```
(base) C:\Users\asukumari>conda info
```

> ```
>  active environment : base
> active env location : C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
>         shell level : 1
>    user config file : C:\Users\asukumari\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\asukumari\.condarc
>       conda version : 4.5.9
> conda-build version : 3.4.1
>      python version : 3.6.4.final.0
>    base environment : C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
>        channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>       package cache : C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
>    envs directories : C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
>                       C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
>                       C:\Users\asukumari\.conda\envs
>            platform : win-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.5.9 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
>       administrator : False
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False
> ```

Comment: conda update --prefix C:\Users\asukumari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

Comment: I installed both Anaconda2 and 3 and now I see conda_console option only under Anaconda2. Why? Is it just one console for both Anaconda2 and 3

Comment: @jalazbe That dint solve it either. I am unable to figure out what to do.

Comment: did you try `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`?

Comment: this is my full error: `PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu
  package name: conda
` your answer doesn't help. Do I change base to the name I give above?

Comment: I think this solved it for me: `export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
source ~/miniconda/bin/activate`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Usually this error, `"PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix."` is because your custom environment doesn't have the conda infrastructure. Instead, it is in your base only. To update the base environment:

```
conda update --name base conda
```

To see what version you have installed:

```
conda list --name base conda
```

example output of list;

```
# packages in environment at /Users/me/miniconda2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
conda                     4.6.14                   py27_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_0
```

Comment: After this I get: PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.

Comment: If you have an activated conda environment, deactivate it `conda deactivate` and then `conda update conda`

Comment: doesn't seem to work. How do I re-install all of conda?

Comment: `conda deactivate` then `conda update conda`

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of getting this error message after typing conda update anaconda. I've added an answer that resolves this for me.

Comment: this is my full error: `PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu
  package name: conda
` your answer doesn't help. Do I change base to the name I give above?

Comment: Worked for me by installing missing conda in `problem_env` from base: `conda install --name problem_env conda`

Comment: Sorry, This did not work using: conda=22.11.1, conda-build=3.22

Answer (score 29):

to solve the problem after message "PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix" package name: anaconda:

```
    conda update --all
    ...
    Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

regards !

Comment: That will update every package in your current env. That seems unlikely to be the goal.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had created and env and I got this error resolved with the command conda update --all. Cheers

Comment: doesn't seem to work. How do I re-install all of conda?

Comment: this is my full error: `PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /dfs/scratch0/brando9/miniconda/envs/metalearning_gpu
  package name: conda
` your answer doesn't help. Do I change base to the name I give above?

Answer (score 10):

Was having the same problem, nothing worked but:

```
conda install anaconda
```

fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. This was really the issue. Anaconda was not installed in the first place. So, I had to install it actually in the specific environment that I was using, and then the rest ...

Answer (score 8):

I got this error when I tried to update while my conda environment was activated. The solution was to first deactivate:

`conda deactivate`

before trying to update:

`conda update conda`

`conda update anaconda`

Comment: I still received this error after changing the environment back to base since anaconda was not in my default channels. Please see my answer for the solution to that if you still get this error message like I did.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the following error when trying to update boto3 in my conda environment:

> PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix. 
>      prefix: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/myfoldername
>
> package name: boto3

This was after having already just done: `conda install anaconda`, `conda update -n root conda` and `conda update --all`

However, I did finally succeed in updating boto3, by specifying the version number as follows:

`conda install boto3=1.12`

Comment: had the same problem after "pip install emcee" - solved by "conda install emcee=3.0.2" ..

Answer (score 4):

When a package is installed via pip in a conda env, and updated via conda, it results in the same error message shown. In this case, use

pip install package_name --upgrade

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem in my window1 10.
pls change the env to base, because the package "conda" only can be updated in base.
regards!

Comment: yup, this is the real solution to the problem. I just did this and it worked, without any extra finagling.

Comment: I still received this error after changing the environment back to base since anaconda was not in my default channels. Please see my answer for the solution to that if you still get this error message like I did.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```py
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Answer (score 1):

I received this error since anaconda was not available in my default channels. I fixed this by forcing the channel to be anaconda as follows:

```
conda install -c anaconda anaconda
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to update base packages from inside the sub environment.

```py
#deactivate the sub env
conda deactivate

#update base if needed
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update --all

#update environment from base
conda update -n yourEnvHere [-c ARepository] --all

#reactivate the env
conda activate yourEnvHere
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this removed the issue when I put it in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
source ~/miniconda/bin/activate
conda activate metalearning_gpu
```

obvious miniconda was int he right place, change that to ur right path to conda stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone encounters the same situation as mine, here's how I solved this problem (by combining some of the solutions above):

```
conda deactivate
conda update --force conda
conda update --all
```

Then in the middle I met another problem

```
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (libarchive.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Solved by running the following command referring to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617946/solve-conda-libmamba-solver-libarchive-so-19-error-after-updating-conda-to-23)

```
curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
bash Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
```

Finally `conda install anaconda`.

Answer (score -6):

This works for me:

```
source active <your python env>
```