# Install package on PyCharm on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to install some packages, and for some reason I can't for the life of me make it happen. My set up is that I'm using PyCharm on Windows with Conda. I'm having these problems with all the non-standard packages I'd like to install (things like numpy install just fine), but for reference I'll use [this](https://github.com/wmayner/pyphi) package. I'll detail all the methods I've tried:

1. Going `File>Settings>Python Interpreter> Install` and then searching for pyphy - it's not found.
2. Adding the URL of in the link above as a repository in PyCharm, and searching again for packages; again not found.
3. Downloading the .tar.gz from the above GitHub, and adding the folder containing that as a repository in PyCharm, then searching for `pyphi` -- again, nothing found.
4. From the terminal in PyCharm, `pip install pyphi`, which gives `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyphy (from versions: none)`
5. From the terminal in pycharm, `conda install -c wmayner pyphi`, which gives a very long error report EDIT: the long error message is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfDNQ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCr7m.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjMg.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzOIa.png), [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwiVR.png). EDIT 2: The error message is now included at the end of this post, as text.
6. With the `.tar.gz` file in the working directory, trying `conda install -c local pyphi-1.2.0.tar.gz`, which gives

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyphi-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

7. Putting the `.tar.gz` file in the directory that the conda virtual environment is installed in, then directing the terminal there, and trying `python pip install pyphi-1.2.0.tar.gz`.

What am I doing wrong?

ERROR MESSAGE FROM APPROACH 5:

```
(MyPy) C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\Dropbox\Nottingham\GPT NNs\MyPy>conda install -c wmayner pyphi
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining @/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0:  33%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎                                                                                                          | 1/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.42it/s]/
failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 265, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 275, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 696, in _add_specs
        raise UnsatisfiableError({})
    conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError:
    Did not find conflicting dependencies. If you would like to know which
    packages conflict ensure that you have enabled unsatisfiable hints.

    conda config --set unsatisfiable_hints True


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 299, in install
        should_retry_solve=(repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 275, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 694, in _add_specs
        ssc.r.find_conflicts(spec_set)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 347, in find_conflicts
        bad_deps = self.build_conflict_map(specs, specs_to_add, history_specs)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 507, in build_conflict_map
        root, search_node, dep_graph, num_occurances)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 369, in breadth_first_search_for_dep_graph
        last_spec = MatchSpec.union((path[-1], target_paths[-1][-1]))[0]
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 481, in union
        return cls.merge(match_specs, union=True)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 475, in merge
        reduce(lambda x, y: x._merge(y, union), group) if len(group) > 1 else group[0]
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 475, in <lambda>
        reduce(lambda x, y: x._merge(y, union), group) if len(group) > 1 else group[0]
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 502, in _merge
        final = this_component.union(that_component)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 764, in union
        return '|'.join(options)
    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Channel found

`$ C:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-script.py install -c wmayner pyphi`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=MyPy
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Anaconda\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Anaconda\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Anaconda\envs\MyPy
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(MyPy)
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Anaconda
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0
DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Dan Goldwater
          MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\plugins\
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda\Library\usr\
                          bin;C:\Anaconda\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\bin;C:\Ana
                          conda\envs\MyPy;C:\Anaconda\envs\MyPy\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anacond
                          a\envs\MyPy\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda\envs\MyPy\Library\bin;C:\Anaco
                          nda\envs\MyPy\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\envs\MyPy\bin;C:\Anaconda\condabin;C
                          :\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\libnvvp;.;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WI
                          NDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32
                          \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
                          2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Program
                          Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program
                          Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2;C:\Program
                          Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
                          Files\Golem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
                          Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram
                          Research\WolframScript;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight
                          Compute 2020.1.2;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA Nv
                          DLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDO
                          WS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Prog
                          ram Files\dotnet;C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
                          Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Dan
                          Goldwater\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\Dan
                          Goldwater\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker
                          Toolbox;C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32;C:\Users\Dan
                          Goldwater\AppData\Local\Pandoc;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
                          Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin;.
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

     active environment : MyPy
    active env location : C:\Anaconda\envs\MyPy
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.0
       base environment : C:\Anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/wmayner/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/wmayner/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda\envs
                          C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

Comment: what you show under item 5 -  `conda: conda install -c wmayner pyphi` is recommended [installation under windows](https://pyphi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation). show your "ver long error report"

Comment: Thanks - it's now edited to include links to the relevant screenshots

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, output, etc. Copy/paste as text, properly formatted. [here is why](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I would suggest to update `conda`  - look at https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/9748 It was merged in 4.8.3 and your version is 4.8.2

Comment: Trying to do this, I get the following error:
```(MyPy) C:\Users\Dan Goldwater\Dropbox\Nottingham\GPT NNs\MyPy>conda update conda

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Anaconda\envs\MyPy
  package name: conda
```
Apologies for the formatting; I don't seem to be able to get line breaks in here.

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Comment: also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712693/packagenotinstallederror-package-is-not-installed-in-prefix I guess you need to deactivate MyPy first

Answer (score 1):

You should do sth like [installation package from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) , but for conda. (replace pip with conda, and provide valid URL). This is not a pypi package, it is not known to pip by default.

Comment: yes, it's available on pypi https://pypi.org/project/pyphi/ but only for linux and macos

Answer (score 0):

In response to @buran's comments above, I updated conda using

`conda update --name base conda`

Then used the recommended install for Windows, with

```
conda install -c wmayner pyphi
```

which now gives the error:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pyphi -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

So at least it's clear why it won't install, and I can create another environment with another version of Python to house it.

Kudos to @buran!