# Should `conda` be installed in every environment?

Tags: conda

I'm running Miniconda and have a question regarding `conda update conda`.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712693/packagenotinstallederror-package-is-not-installed-in-prefix), some answer is (and that's what works) that `conda` needs to be updated in the **base** environment. However, it is possible to also install `conda` in a custom environment and then run `conda update conda`. My questions are:

- Do I need to install `conda` in each new environment or is it "passed through" somehow from the **base** environment?
- If I do install `conda` in a new environment, do I have to update it manually, or will it always be the same version as in **base**?

Reason behind: I want to use a software called `brightway2`. In the manual it says:

> "*To upgrade Brightway2, do the following: First, make sure your background packages are up to date. In anaconda/miniconda, use the following commands (once you have activated your environment)*:
>
> ```
> conda update conda
> conda update -c conda-forge -c cmutel -c haasad brightway2 bw2data bw2io bw2calc bw2analyzer
> ```

I'm stumbling upon the "*(once you have activated your environment)*", which is not possible with updating `conda` in the **base** environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing, looks way cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

You should only have `conda` installed in the base environment (unfortunately, I don't have a reference for this :-().

In the most common case, the `conda` command is defined as a shell function in your login profile (usually `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` on macOS/Linux, I'm not sure about Windows). This is accomplished when you run `conda init`. Since it is defined as a shell function, it will be available no matter which environments are activated, or even if no environments are activated!

If you want to update a package in a specific environment, you can use the `--name`/`-n` flag to tell `conda` which environment to use:

```
conda update --name base conda
```

That will work no matter which environment is activated.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Since I should have conda installed only in the base environment, I wonder what happens when I install conda in other environments additionally.

Comment: I don't recall precisely what will happen, and actually, I've never tested it :-)